# How to add variables to Sigfox callbacks?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, variables, callback, geolocation

I am trying to create a Sigfox callback to AWS. I want to send few variable which include lat and lng variables. But I can't create the callback with lat/long variable because they are not in the "Available variables". However, I've seen others having those variables. How Can I add these variables?

[Json body with lat/long variables. Fails to create the callback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RK0Kg.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [how-to-ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Espc. do not post screen-shots of code, errors etc. Include the text.

Answer (score 0):

The available variables depend on the callback type you are trying to create. If you choose a preexisting AWS callback type, you can only choose between *data/uplink* and *service/data advanced*. Only the *data advanced* type gives you access to *fixedLat* and *fixedLng* (the variables *lat* and *lng* are no longer available).

However, if you want to access more accurate location data, you may want to activate the Sigfox Atlas service. If you do so, you will access an additional computedLocation variables, which will include fields *lat*, *lng* and *computedRadius* (position accuracy in meters). To activate Atlas, you may contact your Sigfox provider.